# Multiple background images for Header,Body, Footer

Tags: html, css, background

I am trying to add the following image as background to the content of a website:
http://webbos.co/vibration/wp-content/themes/vibration-child-theme/images/back1.jpg

http://webbos.co/vibration/

I would like the header part to stay the same size on all pages, the same goes for the footer.
But as the body changes from page to page, i would like it to change accordingly but still fit properly to the header and footer part of the whole image.

I tried different techniques to implement this solution, but couldn't figure it out.
The issue is that the body part of the image doesnt repeat-y so well, as it changes throughout the height of the image,

I would appreciate a solution, and it doesnt matter for me if i have to cut the images to 2 or 3 parts.

Thank you

Comment: Please tell us more or share your code so that we may have a look here

Comment: Anyone got any solution?

Comment: Hi Everyone, 
We are still no found any solution, If any one have any idea about this issue we will really appreciate it

Comment: I think I know what exactly went wrong.

It seems like you applied the image to the body which apparently takes lesser height so please see that your elements inside the body are floated (using css) or the height of the body is increased according to the content (using javascript).

Answer (score -1):

if you are doing it in php den create different `header.php` and `footer.php` and with the background you want and use this code for each page.

```
<body>
<?php include 'header.php';?>

<your middle content>

<?php include 'footer.php';?>
</body>
```

follow this code for each page...
for header and footer background css you may have to use `background-repeat:no-repeat`
and for body `background-repeat:x or y`

Comment: Hi Vishalkin and thanks for your answer, I forgot to mention that I'm using wordpress and I've tried to made it by header/footer/body as you mentioned. the problem with this background is the fact that it not symmetrical so the top & the bottom of the body image suppose to include the top & the bottom of the canvas (the middle part of the image)

Example for the full background image: 
http://webbos.co/vibration/wp-content/themes/vibration-child-theme/images/back1.jpg

My site Link (with the background problem):
http://webbos.co/vibration/

Thanks

Comment: I think I know what exactly went wrong.

It seems like you applied the image to the body which apparently takes lesser height so please see that your elements inside the body are floated (using css) or the height of the body is increased according to the content (using javascript).